# Python using re.sub with a dict to replace quota and apostrophe

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace ' and " in a sting. Here is the dict:

```
char_replace_list = {
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&apos;',
    '&': '&amp;',
    '<': '&lt',
    '>': '&gt',
}
```

This is what I did:

```
s = '\' " & < >'
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(self.char_replace_list.keys()) + r')\b')
pattern.sub(lambda x: char_replace_list[x.group()], s)
```

The result is:

```
' " &amp; &lt; &gt;
```

Where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly I get a different result, with no substitutions at all on my machine.

Your issue is that the edges of those punctuation characters are not considered word boundaries (in a platform-dependent way!?):

> #### `\b`
>
> Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. **A word is defined as a sequence of alphanumeric or underscore characters**, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a non-alphanumeric, non-underscore character. Note that formally, `\b` is defined as the boundary between a `\w` and a `\W` character (or vice versa), or between `\w` and the beginning/end of the string, so **the precise set of characters deemed to be alphanumeric depends on the values of the `UNICODE` and `LOCALE` flags**. For example, `r'\bfoo\b'` matches `'foo'`, `'foo.'`, `'(foo)'`, `'bar foo baz'` but not `'foobar'` or `'foo3'`. Inside a character range, `\b` represents the backspace character, for compatibility with Python’s string literals.

Instead of `\b...\b` you could use `(?<= |^)...(?= |$)`

Answer (score 0):

I this case you can use [translate](http://python-reference.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/str/translate.html) method:

```
char_replace_list = {
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&apos;',
    '&': '&amp;',
    '<': '&lt',
    '>': '&gt',
}
s = '\' " & < >'
# table translate from a mapping
t = "".maketrans(char_replace_list)
print(s.translate(t))
# &apos; &quot; &amp; &lt &gt
```